# Nodejs - User authentication

Tags: linux, windows, node.js, authentication, windows-authentication

I've been wrote a WebAPI service with nodejs and MongoDB, it works great.
The WebAPI service running over linux.
I want the Node service to know the user ID for each request.(The network is Intranet)
I want to use the windows integrate authentication
how can i get the windows userId in the NodeJS service?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think [passport-windowsauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-windowsauth) should be able to take care of it for you.